# Problem writing 'pipe' symbol on danish keyboard (Ubuntu 12.04 server, console)

Tags: command-line, server, xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 Server (32-bit) on an old machine, and have problems writing the `|` (pipe) symbol. I have no graphical UI installed.

My keyboard has danish layout, and all other symbols than `|`, that I have needed, work perfectly. If I change to e.g. US layout, I can write `|`, but of course through a combination that makes little sense on my keyboard, and makes be unable to write special danish symbols that I need.

In `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dk`, under section `xkb_symbols "basic"` there is the line

```
key <AE12> { [ dead_acute, dead_grave, bar, brokenbar ] };
```

which, as I see it, points to the correct key (5th row from bottom, 13th key from left, just to the left of backspace). Also the acute and grave keys works.

I also tried changing to 'eliminate dead keys' (which has a similar line) to no avail.

It's not that AltGr is broken either, since it works well on other key combinations.

Any suggestions as to what may be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have been an old-crappy-keyboard-issue - just connecting another keyboard fixed it. Hope I didn't waste anyone's time on this.